# How to access the values of controls such as textbox and combo box from a user control of another user control on the same page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspx-user-control

I would like to know how I could access the values of a textbox and/or dropdownlist in a user control from another user control that is on the same page. (VB.Net)